# Set a tab to active by adding a class to it using php

Tags: php

What would be a good way to set a tabs class using php? There's no jQuery involved here, only php. I get the tabs name from the script. Based on the `$tab`, I need to set the `<li>` with that name to `class="active"`. Any good ideas on how I can do this?

```
$tab = 'movies';

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li>Books</li>
    <li>Music</li>
    <li class="active">Movies</li>
    <li>Others</li>
</ul>
```

I tried doing this using `str_replace`, but that's all very clumsy and ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a big proponent of directly mixing HTML & PHP, but how about something like this:

```
$options = array("books", "music", "movies", "other");
$tab = 'music';

echo '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">';

foreach($options as $o) {
    if($o == $tab) {
        echo '<li class="active">'.ucfirst($o).'</li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li>'.ucfirst($o).'</li>';
    }
}

echo '</ul>';
```

You could also use PHP's alternative syntax if you are inside the scope of a template:

```
<?php 
    $options = array("books", "music", "movies", "other");
    $tab = 'music';
?>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<?php foreach($options as $o): ?>
    <?php if($o == $tab): ?>
        <li class="active"><?php echo ucfirst($o); ?></li>
    <?php else: ?>
        <li><?php echo ucfirst($o); ?></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice approach. I'm using this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $tabs = array('Books', 'Music', 'Movies', 'Others'); ?>
<ul>
  <?php foreach ($tabs as $tabName): ?>
    <?php $class = ''; ?>
    <?php if ($tab === $tabName) $class = ' class="active"'; ?>
    <li<?php echo $class?>><?php echo $tabName?></li>
  <?php endforeach?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tab = 'movies';

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li <?php if($tab === "Books") { echo class='active'; } ?>>Books</li>
    <li>Music</li>
    <li class="active">Movies</li>
    <li>Others</li>
</ul>
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

How are you generating the navigation? Based on a database? In that case, while retrieving the laels from the database, you can compare them. Otherwise, generate them from an array with the labels, loop through the labels to generate the menu:

```
foreach($labels as $label)
{
if($label == $tab)
{// output active}
else
{regular labels}
```

Comment: No. It's all generated using php. No database involved.